# How do you find the minimum and maximum to see if they match?

Tags: java

How do you find the minimum and maximum to see if they match? But the thing I'm finding the minimum and maximum for integers that are not an array. I need to find the minimum and maximum of the averages and compare them. So far I have this:

```
        int i;
        int totalall = 0;
        int total1 = 0;
        int total2 = 0;
        int total3 = 0;
        int total4 = 0;
        int min1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE, minIndex = 0;
        int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE, maxIndex = 0;
        int average1 = 0;
        int average2 = 0;
        int average3 = 0;
        int average4 = 0;

        System.out.print("Please enter the sample size: ");
        int max = input.nextInt();
        int[]arr0 = new int[max + 1];
        int[]arr1 = new int[max + 1];
        int[]arr2 = new int[max + 1];
        int[]arr3 = new int[max + 1];
        System.out.println("Enter numbers for Trial 0 ");
        for (i = 1;i <= max;i++){
            System.out.print("Enter sample #" + (i-1) + ":");
            arr0[i-1]= input.nextInt();
            total1 = total1 + arr0[i-1];
            }
        System.out.println("Enter numbers for Trial 1 ");
        for (i = 1; i <= max; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter sample #" + (i-1) + ":");
            arr1[i-1] = input.nextInt();
            total2 = total2 + arr1[i-1];
            }
        System.out.println("Enter numbers for Trial 2 ");
        for (i = 1; i <= max; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter sample #" + (i-1) + ":");
            arr2[i-1] = input.nextInt();    
            total3 = total3 + arr2[i-1];
            }
        System.out.println("Enter numbers for Trial 3 ");
        for (i = 1; i <= max; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter sample #" + (i-1) + ":");
            arr3[i-1] = input.nextInt();
            total4 = total4 + arr3[i-1];
            }
        totalall += total1 + total2 + total3 + total4;
        average1 = total1 / (i-1);
        average2 = total2 / (i-1);
        average3 = total3 / (i-1);
        average4 = total4 / (i-1);

        System.out.println("\tSample #\tTrial 0\tTrial 1\tTrial 2\tTrial 3");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + arr3[max] + "\t" + arr0[i-2] + "\t" + arr1[i-2] + "\t" + arr2[i-2] + "\t" + arr3[i-2]);
        System.out.print("Average: \t\t");
        System.out.println(average1 + "\t" + average2 + "\t" + average3 + "\t" + average4);

        for (i=1; i < average; i++);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
var averages = new List<int>(){average1,average2,average3,average4};
var maxAvg = averages.Max();
var minAvg = averages.Min();
```

Answer (score 0):

do you need this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
        int total = 0;
        int avg = 0;
        float count = 0;
        String input = "";

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!(input = scanner.nextLine()).equals("end")) {


            if(max < Integer.parseInt(input))
                max = Integer.parseInt(input);
            else if(min > Integer.parseInt(input))
                min = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if(count == 0)
                max = min = Integer.parseInt(input);
            total += Integer.parseInt(input);
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("max: " + max);
        System.out.println("min: " + min);
        System.out.println("total: " + total);
        System.out.println("avg: " + total / count);        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the minimum of a list of variables (which are not an array) you can let java syntax help you:
The NumberUtils class comes from Apache Commons-Lang library

```
public class ArrayTest {

    public static int min(int ... value)
    {
        return org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils.min(value);
    }
    public static int max(int ... value)
    {
        return org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils.max(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int average1=4, average2=20, average3=40;
        System.out.println("minimum:"+min(average1,average2,average3));
        System.out.println("maximum:"+max(average1,average2,average3));
    }
}
```